# Trying to implement polymorphism with objects

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to implement polymorphism, as can be seen by the code below. I want vector of expressions of type class expression. these expressions will have a right and left parameter object of type Parameter class. As it may have been guessed, this could recurse until one hits a string "a_string" or "an_id." However, the compiler doesn't, first of all, know what type "Expression" is for the vector. Any help is needed. Thank you.

```
#ifndef PARAMETER_H
#define PARAMETER_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Parameter
{

private:
    string a_string;
    string an_id;
    vector<Expression> expressions;



public:
    Parameter(bool expr_stringID);

};

class Expression : public Parameter
{
private:
    Parameter left_parameter;
    Parameter right_parameter;
    char op;

public:

};

#endif
```

Comment: You should be able to just put `class Expression;` just above your `class Parameter` line

Comment: @TheDark Yeah, a forward declaration is the minimum here. Not so sure about the dupe.

Answer (score 2):

*Poymorphism* either requires `virtual` functions (at least a `virtual` destructor), or the CRTP to realize [*Static Polymorphism*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24149851/static-polymorphism-with-crtp-using-the-base-class-to-call-derived-methods).

You provide neither of these with your example.